# Is there a way to automatically convert an object method to an external function?

Tags: python

Just to illustrate let's take:

```
class newobj:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val
    def mul2(self):
        self.value = 2*self.value
```

Is there a way to automatically convert the method `newobj.mul2` to a function `mul2` that can be called like this:

```
o = newobj(5)
mul2(o)
```

Preferably the new function `mul2` will know to assert that the input is an instance of `newobj`, but this is not mandatory.

Comment: `newobj.mul2(o)` but it is going to be the same as `o.mult2()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assign the bound method to a variable:

```
o = newobj(5)
mul2 = o.mul2
```

You don't *have* to call a method in the same expression, you *can* just reference the attribute.

Demo:

```
>>> class newobj:
...     def __init__(self, val):
...         self.value = val
...     def mul2(self):
...         self.value = 2*self.value
...
>>> o = newobj(5)
>>> o.mul2
<bound method newobj.mul2 of <__main__.newobj instance at 0x1059d4440>>
>>> mul2 = o.mul2
>>> o.value
5
>>> mul2()
>>> o.value
10
>>> mul2()
>>> o.value
20
```

If you need a generic 'function' that operates on instances of `newobj`, just reference the method on the class and manually pass in the instance each time:

```
mul2 = newobj.mul2
mul2(o)
```

Demo:

```
>>> o = newobj(5)
>>> mul2 = newobj.mul2
>>> o.value
5
>>> mul2(o)
>>> o.value
10
```

Comment: OP wants to call it as `mul2(o)`, so wouldn't that be `mul2 = newobj.mul2`?

Comment: @tobias_k: I was in the process of adding that option too :-)

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, `mul2 = newobj.mul2` was what I was looking for